# Solve: $y'=\frac{1-3x-3y}{1+x+y}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the homogeneous ODE (or bring it to homogeneous ODE and solve)
>   $$y'=\frac{1-3x-3y}{1+x+y}$$

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$y'=\frac { 1-3x-3y }{ 1+x+y } \\ \\ \\ y=z-x\\ { y }^{ \prime  }={ z }^{ \prime  }-1\\ { z }^{ \prime  }-1=\frac { 1-3z }{ 1+z } \\ { z }^{ \prime  }=\frac { 1-3z }{ 1+z } +1=\frac { 2-2z }{ 1+z } \\ \\ \int { \frac { 1+z }{ 1-z } dz } =2\int { dx } \\ \int { \left( 1+\frac { 2 }{ z-1 }  \right) dz } =-2x+C\\ z+2\ln { \left| z-1 \right| =
-2x+C } \\ x+y+2\ln { \left| x+y-1 \right| =-2x+C } \\ $$

> $$2\ln { \left| x+y-1 \right| =-3x-y+C } \\ \\ $$

Comment: I have came to $2ln|1-z|+z=-2x+c$ how can I isolate $z$?

Comment: I will put full answer here to be more clear

Comment: How did you get to $ \int { \left( 1+\frac { 2 }{ z-1 }  \right) dz } =-2x+C$

Comment: @gbox $\int { \frac { 1+z }{ 1-z } dz } =-\int { \frac { z+1 }{ z-1 }  } dz=-\int { \left( \frac { z-1+2 }{ z-1 }  \right) dz=-\int { \left( 1+\frac { 2 }{ z-1 }  \right) dz } =2x+C } \\ \int { \left( 1+\frac { 2 }{ z-1 }  \right) dz } =-2x+C$

Comment: What a performance in the category "proof without words"...:)

Comment: @JeanMarie,thank you)

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=1+x+y$, $\frac{du}{dx}=1+\frac{dy}{dx}$. So your equation becomes $$\frac{du}{dx}-1=\frac{4}{u}-3$$
$$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{4}{u}-2=\frac{4-2u}{u}$$
$$\frac{u}{4-2u}\frac{du}{dx}=1$$
$$\int\frac{u}{4-2u}\frac{du}{dx}\,dx=x+C$$
$$\int\frac{u}{4-2u}\,du=x+C$$

Now compute the integral, isolate $u$, back substitute to bring back $y$, and isolate $y$.